# How to make h:inputText readonly all time and value should post back

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

By change the combo box value h:inputtext loss behavior for readonly/disable

What should I do?

```
<h:selectOneListbox class="form-control selectpicker" value="{Controller.value}" layout="grid" columns="3">  
  <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.valueList}" var="abc" itemLabel="#{abc.description}" itemValue="#{abc}" />  
  <f:ajax render="panelId2" />
</h:selectOneListbox>

<h:panelGroup styleClass="row row-sm" id="panelId2" layout="block">  
  <div class='input-group date datepicker'/>
  <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="#{Controller.date}" immediate="true" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to explain better your question. Right now it is not clear what you are asking. Provide relevant parts of your code and what you are trying to do.

Comment: <h:selectOneListbox class="form-control selectpicker" value="{Controller.value}" layout="grid" columns="3">  
 <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.valueList}" var="abc" itemLabel="#{abc.description}" itemValue="#{abc}" />  
 <f:ajax render="panelId2" />
</h:selectOneListbox>

Comment: Use `disabled` instead of `readonly` and remove styles if you don't want them.

Comment: <h:panelGroup styleClass="row row-sm" id="panelId2" layout="block">
        <div class='input-group date datepicker'>
  <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="#{Controller.date}" immediate="true" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
  </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>

Comment: Don't write your code like that in comments, edit your post.

Comment: @Geinmachi sorry man i cant post question properly... but let me try with disabled.

Comment: Have you tried `disabled`? Also you have not closed div and [tag:primefaces] tag is unnecessary because you use no PriemFaces components.

Comment: @JorgeCampos after update "panelid" by ajax i got false for facesContext.renderResponse but i want to keep true for each time

Comment: @Geinmachi yes div is already closed its my mistake and yeah primefaces tag is unnecessary

Comment: @Geinmachi yeah now is perfect. you can see this... i am trying with disable

Comment: You forgot `'` in `class` attribute in `div` but that doesn't matter, using `disabled` instead of `readonly` should work.

Comment: with disabled="true" value is not post to back.

Comment: @Geinmachi and with disabled ="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" it is same problem i am facing... when i change the combo box value it will update the h:inputText and then h:inputText loss the disable/readonly behavior.

Comment: @BalusC i have to put it readonly with each view... please look the code... when i update inputText by changing the combo value by ajax request it loss the readonly behavior. but should be able to post back this value

Comment: So, you didn't understand/tried the answer in the duplicate question?

Comment: @BalusC yeah its working with <x:inputXxx ... readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"> thanks dude.... thanks...